# System.InvalidCastException: Column is null when running specific query with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

When executing the following query using EntityFramework (3.1.10) in a webservice running on net5:

```
return _dbContext.Accounts
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Where(a => a.InvitationId.ToLower() == invitation.InvitationId.ToLower())
                    .Where(a => a.Email == invitation.Email)
                    .Where(a => a.AccountNumber == invitation.AccountNumber
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I receive the following error:

```
  An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Context'.
  System.InvalidCastException: Column is null
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue[T](Int32 ordinal)
     at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 ordinal)
```

The message doesn't specify which column the problem is but there is only one column of type int, which is the `Status` column. This column does however have a value.

I have tried to reproduce this issue in a development environment, copying the exact column values in my local database and using the exact same request body that causes this issue.
This didn't give me the same exception, which led me to believe that there is a difference in the database between the two environments. We update the model using code migrations and having checked all columns of the specific table everything seems fine.

Another thing is that other queries on the same table don't seem to cause this exception.

Is there a way to find out which column exactly is giving me issues?

Comment: "The message doesn't specify which column the problem is but there is only one column of type int" -> you're reading the stack trace wrong -> `int` is for the **position** of the column, not the type of data that is being read, which is a `string` (from `GetString`)

Comment: I am not aware to know the column name, but the stack trace points to a wrongfully defined string column (your database allowing NULL values but your EF not allowing them in that string property)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have figured out which column is giving me issues, when I update that column with a value instead of `null` the exception is gone.
That field needs to accept `null` value though and the model has that property as follows: `public string? Name { get; set; }`. This actually gave me the following warning: `The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a '#nullable' annotations context`.
I read that adding `#nullable enable` might be a fix for that?